# Javascript var a = function b() {}

Tags: javascript

```
var a = function b() {
    console.log( typeof b === 'function' );
};
a();  // true
console.log( typeof b === 'function' );  // false
```

Why the second result is false?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a *named function expression*.

Its name is only visible inside the function.

For much more information, see [this article](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/)