# Getting error when declare function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I have something like this

```
var a = function b(){};
a() // it's work
b() // error b is not define
```

I know that no one will declare a function like this. But why javascript dont thrown an error when I coding like this. But when I start calling the function by call b() It thrown an error.

Can anybody explain me why?

Comment: A is a var that equals the function b, which means it calls on b() when you do the call a(); 
you'll get the error on b(); "is not defined" because its the assigned value. 
Pretty much you are trying to call the assigned value which would be like:
var a = "b";
and then you try call the string "b"();

Comment: Yeah, that's make sense for me. Thanks alot. :D
But still wonder why javascript don't thrown an error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a named function expression.

Its name is only visible inside the function as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17584411/2174170)

Comment: IE 6 had a bug where named function expressions became functions in an outer scope. But hopefully those days are gone… ;-)

Comment: I never knew that, interesting info :)

Answer (score 0):

You have put function b in var a
When using 'var' your variable can be any type and in this case it becomes 'function b'

So b is not defined

Comment: so what is 'function b' in javascript . Look like it doesn't make any sense. 
And also when you call a() . this function still run normally :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Javascript is a weakly typed language
2. `var a = function b(){};` is a valid declaration, but the scope of b is limited to a only. You cannot access it outside that.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Types. The OP isn't a function declaration, it's a function expression.

Answer (score 0):

This function always return value

```
var a = function b(){};
```

Answer (score -1):

Why you don't do that :

`a = function(){
   ... code function a ..
  }
b = function(){
   ... code function b ..
  }`

After you call function by `a();` and `b();`